# Can a Docker container manage other Docker containers?

Tags: docker, multi-tenant, coreos

I need to be able to deploy a new container or manage Docker containers running in CoreOS from another running docker container.

Docker version is `1.5.0`
CoreOS version is `647.2.0`

Right now my process for deploying a new instance of my application is using a shell script.

It basically does:

1. duplicate the source code of the Node.js application to a new folder
2. cd into it
3. deploy a new docker container in detached mode setting `pwd` as `-v` to the work directory then the application runs

I was thinking, if it's possible to execute the shell script from inside the container so that it deploys a new container in CoreOS or are there any alternatives for this method.

Another objective is to be able to stop a running container.

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can configure the Docker daemon to listen on `docker0`, then you can use the [docker remote API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run the controlling container with the Docker client & socket mounted and you will be able to control the docker daemon from within your containers (run docker *client* within docker *container*)

*EDIT: DO note root access is required to the docker socket, this means the container is able to control the docker daemon and launch a containter to get root on the host, so use this with containers you trust and only you need to access.*

```
$ docker run \ 
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \   
  -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \ 
  -v /usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02 \
  ubuntu docker --version

Docker version 1.1.2, build d84a070
```

also tested on latest coreOS / Docker:

```
core@coreos2 /usr/lib $ docker run -it --name=test --rm -h=dod -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v `which docker`:/usr/bin/docker -v /usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02 ubuntu bash
root@dod:/# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6746d8cd1c8d        ubuntu:latest       "bash"              3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            test
root@dod:/# docker --version
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2-dirty
root@dod:/#
```

EDIT: for debian:jessie this wouldn't work without libsqlite3-0, we can mount it form the host or search for the package:

```
root@066bf3df3f2e:/# ldd `which docker`
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdb7dc8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe8a77df000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => not found
        libdevmapper.so.1.02 => /usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02 (0x00007fe8a7593000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe8a71ea000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe8a79fc000)
        libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007fe8a6fdb000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe8a6dd3000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe8a6bcf000)
```

to find out which package provides this file for debian:jessie use [packages.debian.org/search](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libsqlite3.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=amd64)

EDIT: the user within the container will need to have permission to read the docker socket from the host, if it is a non-root user, you could try to have a `docker` group within the container, but the group `gid` should match to host `docker` group (unconfirmed if this actually works).

Alternatively you could `apt-get install sudo` and

```
echo "<user_name> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/90-custom && \
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/90-custom
```

at which point you can write scripts for that user to `sudo docker ..` control the host docker daemon.

Comment: Sorry,  I'm using docker version 1.5.0 and I tried this it didn't work

Comment: strange, it has been a while since I used this, but I'd expect it still to work, let me test

Comment: sorry, it's actually working I just have to add proper docker directory setup. Thank you very much!

Comment: ok, thanks, in the mean time - my CoreOS hyper-v machine doesn't want to boot, so I downloaded a fresh one from http://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/current/ but I can't get the cloud-config to work (while I did manage to do that last time :( :( ) so I've not been able to test so far...

Comment: fyi - mkisofs no longer seems to work, I fixed my issue using a vhd config-drive

Comment: cool!  just 1 note if you use `which docker` from a remote client it could be the docker host has the binary under a different path, so perhaps it is safer to replace this with the full path to the docker binary on the docker daemon.

Comment: I use it in docker composer, thats why `which docker` is not usable staticly in yaml. By the way, i use it with logrotate, for logs stored inside my containers with `postrotate docker kill -s HUP container_apache`. Hope it can help someone